# New user default picture?

Tags: discussion, support, profile-page, profile-picture

Recently, I have noticed that the default picture assigned to a new user have changed. We no more have the random colorful pattern. Instead we have the First Letter within a colored background (like Google is doing).

[image]

[image]

Is this a new feature or a simple coincidence among the users I saw? Or maybe I missed a Meta discussion about this?

Comment: When I look at a user with that type of icon's edit page, it's from "Google"... not quite sure what that means... possibly they have a gmail address/use gmail to log in?

Comment: Going to [Users > New Users > Creation Date](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=NewUsers&sort=creationdate) I'm seeing several that still have the old one. It might just be that these users have Google accounts and imported that avatar? (Don't at all remember if that import is auto or not, I think Facebook is but don't know on Google.)

Comment: @Catija I see, so maybe they kept their default Gmail avatar and it's getting imported with their name too

Comment: You can register on Stack Overflow with your Google account. The profile picture is most likely imported from Google like it is from Facebook.

Comment: if it is not already written among the advice I suggest you access Gravatar https://it.gravatar.com/